# Grails 2 with the JSF 2 plugin?

Tags: grails, jsf-2, primefaces, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

Is anyone using Grails 2.0 or later with the [JSF plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jsf2)? I’m a little hesitant to start using Grails with JSF because the plugin page says it was last updated in April of 2010 (it’s at version 0.1) and it goes with Grails 1.2.

I’m asking because I read a blog post that uses [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) with Grails 1.3.7, and for some reason I’ve been sitting here wondering which one I’ll use, when in reality I would love to use both of them together. (My boss is using Grails 2.0 right now.)

So in short, is it possible to use Grails 2 with JSF using either this plugin or an alternative method, and is anyone already doing this?

When I try to install the plugin through the plugin manager I get this(In the Groovy/Grails ToolSuite)

```
Problems occurred (un)installing plugins. See details for more information
------System.out:-----------
 | Loading Grails 2.1.1
| Configuring classpath
| Downloading: jstl-1.2.pom.sha1
| Downloading: servlet-api-2.5.pom.sha1
| Downloading: jstl-1.2.jar.sha1
| Downloading: servlet-api-2.5.jar.sha1
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for     more information):

- javax.faces:jsf-api:2.0.2-FCS
- javax.faces:jsf-impl:2.0.2-FCS


------System.err:-----------
```

Comment: Did you get any progress using Grails 2 and Primefaces 4 ?

Comment: This was a long time ago I'm not really working on similar stacks anymore but it seems like I remember I had to generate a web.xml and change it to match a JSF like web.xml. Afterwords this didn't work leaving the web.xml in the default location it had to be moved to where the webserver was actually looking for it in Grails Tool Suite rather than the default location. To finish it off I think I had to create beans in the beans file to find the with EL expressions rather than use the default controllers although I think controllers ended up just having odd names and I could use them. Huge Hack.